# XCode + Applescript App | Add Preferences to the App

Tags: xcode, applescript, interface-builder

I created an App that start stop system daemons. I also created a preferences `Window` inside the project and linked to the `Preferences (⌘,)` menu item. Inside this preferences window I have a few `Text Field` boxes like Apache Path, MySQL Path and so on.

I want to *"link"* these boxes to the Info.plist of the app (or force the app to create it's own plist inside Application Support). Whenever these are edited and the user click OK the plist should also be written.

I also need to read these from the plist for the `applicationWillFinishLaunching`  so it gets populated when the app starts

I've tried many different approaches, but none worked. The plist is never written, or read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Thank to the guys at MacScripter, they rock!! Here is how:

### The IBActions:

> ```
> property configOK : missing value
> property apacheLocation : ""
> property pathApache : missing value
> ```

### Initialisation, read the value from the app domain plist (if exists, if not try to detect)

> on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
>
> ```
> tell standardUserDefaults() of current application's NSUserDefaults
>     registerDefaults_({apacheLocation:apacheLocation})
>
>     set apacheLocation to objectForKey_("apacheLocation") as text
>     if apacheLocation is "" then
>         pathApache's setStringValue:(do shell script "source $HOME/.bash_profile; which apachectl")
>         else
>         pathApache's setStringValue: objectForKey_("apacheLocation")
>     end if end tell
> ```

### Save prefs variables upon "Prefs OK Button" clicked

> ```
> on configOK_(sender)
>     set apacheLocation to pathApache's StringValue() as text
> end configOK_
> ```

### App is ending, write the values to the plist

> ```
> on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
>     tell standardUserDefaults() of current application's NSUserDefaults
>         setObject_forKey_(apacheLocation, "apacheLocation")
>     end tell
> ```

Here is the App :D btw:
[my little nasty app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHLC8.png)